# Rails: Making Settingslogic work with Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, settingslogic

I can't seem to run Cucumber tests on views that include strings governed by [Settingslogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic).

```
Scenario: Login as an existing user from homepage
    Given a user exists
    And I am on the home page
      can't convert nil into Hash (ActionView::TemplateError)
      On line #4 of app/views/home/index.html.haml

          1: #greeting
          2:   #lady= image_tag 'svg/lady.svg'
          3:   %h1= image_tag 'logo.png'
          4:   %p= "#{Settings.website.name} is still under development."
```

How can I add Settingslogic to my test environment so this will pass?

I've tried:

**config/environments/test.rb**

```
config.gem 'settingslogic', :lib => false
```

**config/environments/cucumber.rb**

```
config.gem 'settingslogic', :lib => false
```

**features/support/env.rb**

```
require 'settingslogic'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `app/config/application.yml` do you have a cucumber section?  If not, add this:

```
cucumber:
    <<: *defaults
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was missing. Thanks!